# How to open(start) app when FCM notification recieives without tapping the notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are developing an taxi management application where the ride request are managed through FCM, When the rider request for a trip driver will get fcm message. What i need to accomplish is to open the app if it is in background when the ride request arrives. How can i achieve this

is it possible to open or start iOS app without touching the notification?

Comment: no...this feature is not available

Comment: What does means by start? need to bring the app to foreground or running the task in background?

Comment: if the application is in background it has to be opened(bring it to foreground)

Comment: No, you can't. I think you should make this app in the Android like Uber or Grab

Comment: we already have the app, and we need to add something for driver app to tell driver that one trip request is arriving when the app is in background state

Comment: This behavior describes a what seems to be a [pop-up ad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-up_ad). *Unwanted and frowned upon*. Imagine an app just comes to the top of your device without your say so. Good thing this is not possible for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using iOS VoIP Push Notifications.

Here is great [Apple guide about Voice Over IP (VoIP) Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html), what is the best way to use VoIP Push Notifications. One of the main use case – use VoIP Push Notifications to Avoid Persistent Connections.

In order to use VoIP pushes you have to connect [iOS PushKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit) and you have to [Configuring APNs with FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)

**Please note:** Firebase might not support VoIP push kit services. You can get help from firebase support team. You can [config your own server](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios8-apps-and-pushkit/#the%20server-side%20code) or other third party provider.

Comment: As you suggested I have implemented Voip Push notification in my app still it does not open the app automatically I have to fire a local notification and when i tap that notification app lunches. Please help me if i have forgot something.

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s not possible to open app without tapping the notifications due to IOS limitations.
You have to tap notifications to open app.